# Filter in functional languages with original non-filtered elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, scala, functional-programming

I want to return an array that that maps some filtered elements - but I want to keep the non-filtered elements where they are.
i.e. Is there an easy way to do this?:

```
array
.filter(
  function(element){
    // some test
  }
)
.map(
  function(element){
    // some mapping
  }
)
```

The closest solution I've come up with is something along the lines of:

```
array
.map(
  function(value, index){
    if (<test>) {
      return <mapping>(value);
    }
  }
)
```

but I feel this somewhat breaks the spirit of functional programming.

I'm not asking for a specific language implementation, although an example in Scala or JavaScript would be nice.

EDIT: Here's a concrete example of what I'm looking for:

```
[1,2,3,4,11,12]
```

Mapping all elements to element*10, for all elements in array which are greater than 10, should yield

```
[1,2,3,4,110,120]
```

EDIT2: I apologize for using the word "mutate."  I did not mean mutate the original array - I was thinking more along the lines of mutating a copy of the array.

Comment: The second code doesn't mutate anything. Unless you're programming in a yet-unknown Javascript version that has pass-by-reference.

Comment: Fixed, although the code ends up looking even worse.

Comment: Can you provide pseudo-code of what you would like the functional-style syntax to look like?

Comment: Something along the lines of the first code snippet - I want to separate the test function from the mutation function.

Comment: I'm missing something obviously:  isn't your first example exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: `filter` returns a new array consisting of the elements for which the callback function returns true. Mapping/mutating this new array does nothing for me - I need the return the full array with the mutated elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really going to be functional if you're using a mutable collection. But you can use `transform` in Scala:

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4,11,12)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12)

scala> a.transform {i => if(i > 10) i * 10 else i}
res10: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int] = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 110, 120)
```

**edit:**
If you want filter and map separated, use a `view`:

```
scala> a
res22: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12)

scala> a.view.filter(_ > 10).transform(_ * 10)
res23: scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView[Int,Array[Int]] = SeqViewF(...)

scala> a
res24: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 110, 120)
```

Comment: The test for condition and actual mapping are too close to each other.  As an example, changing the code to make it just map and skip the condition would turn it into something along the lines of `a.transform {i => i * 10}`.  Adding a condition back in would require me to "re-wrap" the mapping in a condition (`if` before, `else` after).

Answer (score 2):

Is `collect` what you are after?

```
scala> List(2, 3, 5, 6, 9).filter(_ < 5).map(_ * 100)
res30: List[Int] = List(200, 300)

scala> List(2, 3, 5, 6, 9).collect { case i if i < 5 => i * 100 }
res31: List[Int] = List(200, 300)
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for slightly modified version: `List(2, 3, 5, 6, 9).collect { case i if someFilter(i) => someMap(i); case i => i}`

Comment: @Jamil: This is not `collect`, this is `map`.

Comment: @Debilski And, yet, that's what he asked for.

Comment: Jamil, Daniel: Yes, I should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide your filter and map function to a 'combining' function; I've tried an example on http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/UDbyL/.

The idea is to apply the 'mapping' (which I would call *inplace mapping*) to all elements conforming to the filtering predicate *in the original array*.

Answer (score 2):

Although these sorts of operations are possible in principle, the Scala library does not provide them.

You can build your own using indices (or views on indices):

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> a.indices.view.filter(i=>a(i)%2==0).foreach(i=>a(i)=0)

scala> a
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 0, 3, 0, 5)
```

It's slightly awkward, but usually a little better than the if-statement version (in that at least you can see the filter and assignment steps separately).

Answer (score 1):

Hej jiaweihli

the easiest solution is to reassign it to the reference ... ie mutating the reference
and not the data. This has some benefits if the reference is in other places you
are not mutating it under there noses.

EX:

```
x = x.filter(filterOpp);
```

ps! the second example there dosent work.
GL

Comment: This won't work, since it will only return me the filtered array.  I want the original array, where the filtered array elements have been mutated.

Comment: So first of thats not functional att all you are cinda missing the point. You dont want you program to depend on referenced getting mutated under them. Putt a layer of indirection between them like an object with a method to get the curent version of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are thinking of filtering, and filtering is *not* what you want. If you don't want to remove elements, it is not a filter.

All you need is a simple map:

```
array.map(x => if(x > 10) x * 10 else x)
```

Or, if you think your conditions are too complex,

```
array.map {
    case x if x > 10 => x * 10
    case x => x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: (psuedo javascript)

```
  filteredMap = function(element) {
    if(filterFunc(element)){
      return mapFunc(element);
    }
    return element;
  }


  array = array.map(filteredMap)
```

Unless you explicitly are required to mutate the array (which isn't "functional") this should get you what you want.